# Text doesn't appear in Capybara but does in dev environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, capybara

I'm working a on sample application to practice TDD. I have the following test:

```
scenario 'without an author' do
  create_post("RULEZ")
  expect(page).to have_content("Author can't be blank")
end
```

where create post is in a helper file:

```
  def create_post(body, author = nil)
    visit '/posts/new'
    fill_in 'post[body]', with: body
    select author, from: 'post[author]' if author
    click_on 'Create Post'
  end
```

So if I manually follow this flow, I get an 'Author can't be blank' error message as expected if I leave out author. However, when Capybara does the same thing, the body validations show up but the author validation doesn't (verified by using save_and_open_page via Launchy gem).

Here's my author model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 7 }
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

Here's how I'm displaying validation errors:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.valid?
      @post.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:errors] = @post.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end
```

In my application.html.erb:

```
  <body>
    <% if flash[:errors] %>
      <% flash[:errors].each do |error| %>
        <%= error %>
        <br />
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
```

Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Comment: How are you displaying the validation errors?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Added in my post

Comment: Have you checked the params submitted in `test.log` to make sure it's not actually submitting a default author_id value?